# More literary translation of “Lass bitte bald was von dir hören”

Tags: meaning-in-context, german-to-english

> Lass bitte bald was von dir hören.

The above sentence means

> Write/get in touch soon.

But I want a more detailed (literary) English translation, especially for the *was* and *von.*

Comment: A *literary* translation would be in the style of high literature. Do you mean a more *literal* one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A literary translation would be:

> Please, let [me] hear something from you soon.

But of course, this isn't a very idiomatic translation.

- *Lass* = imperative form of *lassen*
- *was* = short form of *etwas (something)*
- *von dir = from you*

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question to mean a more *literal* (not *literary*) translation, because you also said you want *"a more detailed (..) English translation, especially for the **was** and **von**."*

The most literal I can imagine would be this:

**Let please soon something from you hear.**

*Lass bitte bald was von dir hören.*